# Firefox not displaying Italic Font correctly - while other browsers do

Tags: css, firefox, fonts

I'm trying to use a font called ***SF Distant Galaxy*** in my webpage (which I think I download from here: https://www.dafont.com/sf-distant-galaxy.font)

The problem is that while I'm specifying to use the ***ITALIC*** version of this font, Firefox insists on displaying only the **REGULAR** version of it. 
Meanwhile, all the other Browsers I've tried (Safari, Chrome, and Opera) *are* showing the italic font correctly.

WHY?

Here's my `CSS`code:

```
.Lithium-Text-Class, .V-Text-Class, .TEXT-2-Class {
   font-family: SFDistantGalaxy-Italic, 'SF Distant Galaxy';
}
```

**PLEASE NOTE:** this `CSS` was automatically generated by Adobe Illustrator after I exported an illustration I created in it as an `SVG` file. So I didn't write this `CSS` code myself. I'm actually not sure why it puts single quotes around the regular version of the font but not around the Italic version, but again: this works on every browser I've tried *except* for Firefox, so I assume it's correct and it's a Firefox issue, not a code issue.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your svg's css should also include a `font-style` property like so:

```
.Lithium-Text-Class, .V-Text-Class, .TEXT-2-Class {
   font-family: 'SF Distant Galaxy';
   font-style: italic;
}
```

`SFDistantGalaxy-Italic` is a local font name,
`'SF Distant Galaxy'` - family names containing whitespace characters always need to be wrapped in quotes.

Most likely the font is installed locally but not referenced via [`@font-face`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face)

It is therefore not displayed unless a visitor happens to have the "SF Distant Galaxy" font on his system.

Your websites's main stylesheet needs a `@font-face` like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "SF Distant Galaxy";
  font-weight:400;
  font-style:normal;
  src: url("fonts/SF Distant Galaxy.ttf") format("truetype");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "SF Distant Galaxy";
  font-weight:400;
  font-style:italic;
  src: url("fonts/SF Distant Galaxy Italic.ttf") format("truetype");
}
```

This way the browser can map a `font-family` name as well `font-style` to the  correct font file.

Make sure your path to the font-file is correct, otherwise you'll see a fallback font.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'SF Distant Galaxy';
  src: url('data:font/woff2;charset=utf-8;base64,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') format('woff2');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'SF Distant Galaxy';
  src: url('data:font/woff2;charset=utf-8;base64,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') format('woff2');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: italic;
}

body {
  font-family: "SF Distant Galaxy";
}
```

```html
<p>Regular <em>italic</em></p>
```

In the above example I've used [transfonter](https://transfonter.org) to generate a font subset converted to a data url. The text will switch automatically between regular and italic since we have mapped both font files for different styles using the same family name.

Furthermore: **Firefox might not display local fonts** due to security settings.
However you can adjust [this setting as described here.](https://support.mozilla.org/no/questions/1355994#answer-1455437)